# Check if todays date is before or after a date held in sql

Tags: php, html, sql

I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Date that is stored in database, get put there using this

```
    $date2=Date('d/m/y', strtotime("+90 days"));
```

Stored in column with this info
    varchar(255)    latin1_swedish_ci

Output:

```
    $get_w_date = $qr['r_e_date']; 
    print"
   <tr><th colspan=\"2\"> <b>Warranty Status</b> </th></tr>";
   if(strtotime($get_w_date) > time()) {
   echo '<tr bgcolor=\"ff00ff\"> outcome 1';
   } else {
   echo '<tr bgcolor=\"00ff00\"> outcome 2';
   }
```

It always runs outcome 2 regardless of the date in the database being before now or not :(

Comment: You should not store dates in `varchar` fields, that will make comparissons and sorting in sql a lot harder.

Comment: @jeroen - especially with **that** date format.

Comment: What is wrong with the date format?

Answer (score 0):

This is a lot easier if you didn't store your dates as strings.

Try using [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) and [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp). Your SQL:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(r_e_date, "%m/%d/%y")) as r_e_date
```

Your PHP:

```
$get_w_date = $qr['r_e_date']; 
if($get_w_date > time()) {
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code is for checking if the saved date is ***1 day before or after:***

```
<?php
$date = date('Y-m-d');
Echo "Today : $date<br/>";

$saved = "2013-12-29";  // For output i set the date instead of $qr['r_e_date']; 
$previous_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($saved .' -1 day'));
Echo "Previous to saved date : $previous_date<br/>";

$next_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($saved .' +1 day'));
Echo "Next to saved date : $next_date<br/><br/>";

if($previous_date == $date)
{
Echo "Before";
}
else if($next_date == $date)
{
Echo "After";
}
?>
```

Note for the above code to work date in database must be stored in `Y-m-d`(Year-month-date) format.

---

If you want to ***remove the 1 day limit*** you can use the following code to check *before,after or same date*:

```
<?php
$date = date('Y-m-d');
Echo "Today : $date<br/>";
$todayA=explode("-",$date);

$saved = "2014-01-03";  // For output i set the date instead of $qr['r_e_date']; 
Echo "Saved : $saved<br/><br/>";
$savedA=explode("-",$saved);

if($savedA[0]==$todayA[0])
{
    if($savedA[1]==$todayA[1])
    {
        if($savedA[2]==$todayA[2])
        {
        Echo "Same Date";
        }
        else if($savedA[2]<$todayA[2])
        {
        Echo "Before";
        }
        else
        {
        Echo "After";
        }
    }
    else if($savedA[1]<$todayA[1])
    {
    Echo "Before";
    }
    else
    {
    Echo "After";
    }
}
else if($savedA[0]<$todayA[0])
{
Echo "Before";
}
else
{
Echo "After";
}
?>
```

Comment: Won't that only work if today is 1 day before or after?

Comment: Can it be made to work using >= and <= for all before and all after rather than ==?

Comment: Ok I will add that script later(may be today or tomorrow because i m busy now).Check for an update later.